# VB.net HttpWebRequest returns 403 forbidden when ressource is available

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

hello i was using the code for a while in my vb.net app but today when i tried it it returned a 403 error.

```
Shared Function GetHtmlPage(ByVal http://mmo-stream.net/AiaSpecto/tester.php As String) As String

    Dim strResult As String
    Dim objResponse As WebResponse
    Dim objRequest As WebRequest

    objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)

    objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse()
    Using sr As New StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream())
        strResult = sr.ReadToEnd()
        sr.Close()
    End Using
    Return strResult

End Function
```

I really cant understand why i get a 403 error because when i go on the link itself i get the OK message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request wants a useragent header.
If you change the object to `HttpWebResponse` and `HttpWebRequest` and add a generic useragent it should return OK :

```
Dim objResponse As HttpWebResponse
Dim objRequest As HttpWebRequest
objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(strURL)
objRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36"
objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse()
```

Comment: thanks worked a lot, why did before websites didnt care for useragant but now they do? do you know?

Comment: Sorry I'm not 100% sure why but I have noticed it too. Can only assume it's to try and make sure it only returns 200s to actual user's browsers.